# what is the web server in glassfish application server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, webserver

Can someone tell me the name of the web server embedded in glassfish. I know there are web servers like apache/jersey/jetty. Which one is embedded inside glassfish by default? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glassfish uses Grizzly framework for web server. See Project Grizzly for reference. Refer your server logs when it starts, it says about Grizzly framework there.